# Can someone please tell me why this form does not submit when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

We would like our users to click the "Transfer" button and then have the values populated in the javascript below.

However, when I click the button, it doesn't fire.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
<input type="button" value="Transer" />
</form>
<script>
$.post("exhume.aspx",
    { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: $("#user").val(),Password: $("#pass").val() }) },
    function (data) {
        var token = JSON.parse(data);
    }
);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is posting without a click event. is that what you want?

Comment: [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/);

Comment: Set the button type to submit, and capture that event instead of the click event.

Comment: you didn't code for it to submit when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the `script` tag is executed right as the page is loaded, which means it `POST`s right when you load the page. To have it fire on the `click` event, you need to attach an event-handler to the button. Otherwise there is no way that the browser will know to execute your code when the button is clicked.

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
<input id="transfer" type="button" value="Transer" />
</form>
<script>
$("#transfer").click(function() {
    $.post("exhume.aspx",
        { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: $("#user").val(),Password: $("#pass").val() }) },
        function (data) {
            var token = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    );

});

</script>
```

An easier option is to simply bind to the `submit` event on the form:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
<input type="button" value="Transer" />
</form>
<script>
$("#form1").submit(function() {
    $.post("exhume.aspx",
        { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: $("#user").val(),Password: $("#pass").val() }) },
        function (data) {
            var token = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    );    
});

</script>
```

Comment: All of you are absolutely fantastic. I am truly grateful for the prompt responses.

Unfortunately, I can only select ONE correct answer.

How do I dispay the value from the params?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `click handler` for that button,

Try this,

```
$('#form1 input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    $.post("exhume.aspx",
       { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: $("#user").val(),Password: $("#pass").val() }) },
         function (data) {
         var token = JSON.parse(data);
       }
    );    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here:

1.You need to attach the function to the submit event.
2. You need to prevent the default behaviour of the form so that the page does not refesh

```
 $("#form1").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("exhume.aspx",
        { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: $("#user").val(),Password: $("#pass").val() })      },
        function (data) {
        var token = JSON.parse(data);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function() {
    $.post("exhume.aspx",
        { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: $("#user").val(),Password: $("#pass").val() }) },
        function (data) {
            var token = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Also, change the type of the Transfer button to `submit`

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating this quite a bit. You don't need to manually create the data string.

You can simply do:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="exhume.aspx">
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
  <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
  <input type="button" value="Transer" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  $.post( $form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(){
    alert('The form was submitted!');
  }); 
});
```

This approach will allow the form to submit even if JS is not available.